# TypeScript compiling fine, but still getting intellisense errors

Tags: visual-studio-2015, typescript1.7

Very frustrating, I am in a situation where TypeScript is compiling fine, but I am still getting Intellisense errors.

This is TypeScript 1.7 in Visual Studio 2015, Update 1.

[image: Error saying TypeScript 1.5 feature. Current language level is 1.4.]

[image: Error saying Symbol Component cannot be properly resolved, probably it is located in inaccessible module.]

When I make a change and hit save however, it compiles fine, and the underlying Javascript gets updated.

Any ideas?

Cheers

Comment: Did you manage to find a resolution to this?  I have noticed that this doesn't happen with the alpha versions of angular.

Comment: It was ReSharper, you can set the version in the RS settings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could check out your .csproj file if you have a c#-based project. Sometimes there's an incorrect version of typescript. Look for a string with:

```
<TypeScriptToolsVersion>version</TypeScriptToolsVersion>
```

There should be 1.7.

Comment: I have the same issue and my csproj file says 1.7 but I still get the intellisense error...